# Strange Behaviour With MouseEnter Event

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm developing a windows phone 8 XAML application.

I defined MouseEnter events for several objects in a XAML page. (For example two rectangles). After triggering the MouseEnter events of those objects, I press a button on the same page. Button press does not only trigger click event of it self. It also triggers MouseEnter event of the last Rectangle entered.

The problem can be reproduced with a new project with just two Rectangles and one Button. This behaviour does not appear always, but can be observed after triggering MouseEnter event of the Rectangles a few times.

My XAML objects are as follows.

```
<Rectangle Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100"
           Margin="102,306,0,0" Stroke="Black" 
           VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" 
           MouseEnter="Rectangle_MouseEnter"/>

<Rectangle Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" 
           Margin="314,306,0,0" Stroke="Black" 
           VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"
           MouseEnter="Rectangle_MouseEnter"/>

<Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Margin="256,481,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Button_Click"/>
```

And code behind looks like this.

```
private void Rectangle_MouseEnter(object sender, 
                                  System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Rectangle_MouseEnter");
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Button_Click");
}
```

Comment: Does your `Button` overlap with your rectangles?

Comment: They are far away from each other.

Comment: given that there isn't normally a mouse on windows phone, what are you trying to do with mouseenter that you couldn't do with some other gesture related things that are more appropriate on winphone?

Comment: Hello John, There isn't an event such as TouchEnter. Single tap events are named Mouse events. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207076(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: I'm not able to recreate this. Does it only happen on certain hardware? You've also not included the `Button_MouseEnter` event handler. Could this be related?

Comment: Hi Matt, Button_MouseEnter event handler is irrelevant. I've deleted it. It happens on emulator and also on my Lumia 925 device.

Comment: I could reproduce it too, the way to reproduce it is slide your finger from oustide the rectangle and then release it when you are inside, and then each time you press the button you will get the Mouse enter event unless you press somewhere on the screen.

Comment: from what I see the Mouse enter get fired again when you release the button and the enter point passed is the exact same point as the point that the rectangle MouseLeave was fired.

Comment: It seem like a bug in windows phone so you probably just need to use a workaround, for example MouseMove don't seem to be fired so maybe you can use that instead

Comment: or use a flag that you set when pressing the button and unset in a dispatcher

Comment: Luckily the button click event fired first and MouseEnter right after. I use a workaround, ignoring the mousenter event for 50 ms after a button click.

Comment: You may call me a grammar nazi, but shouldnt it say wpf application instead of xaml application?

Answer (score -1):

If I remember, in Windows pone and Windows 8 apps it's better to use the tapped event instead of mouse events. It could be the problema. Take a look on this link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.tapped.aspx